# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Функция <calc_square> выполняется неверно, хотя выглядит аналогично что и функция <calc_perimeter>. Не могу разобраться, что от меня требуется?

```
from typing import Text


a = input('Введите первую сторону: ')
b = input('Введите вторую сторону: ')

def calc_perimeter(side_a, side_b):
    return (side_a)*2 + (side_b)*2

def calc_square(side_a, side_b):
    return (side_a) * (side_b)


def show_info(side_a, side_b):
    p = calc_perimeter(side_a, side_b)
    s = calc_square(side_a, side_b)
    Text = 'Периметр = ' + str(p) + 'м., '
    Text += 'площадь = ' + str(s) + ' кв.м.'
    return Text

print(show_info(a, b))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у вас `a` и `b` это строки и при попытке умножить их друг на друга происходит ошибка. Их надо превратить в число

```
a = int(input('Введите первую сторону: ')) 
b = int(input('Введите вторую сторону: '))
```

Comment: А как же isdigit или try except? ;)